# monacaでnendを使って広告表示の方法

Tags: javascript, monaca, nend

現在、monacaを使用しましてnendでインタ-スティシャル広告(全画面広告)を表示させようとしています。monacaはjavascriptを使って実装をしているのですが、nend側でそのコードがなくて困っています。まず、インタースティシャル広告はmonacaで使用はできますか？また、javascriptのコードがあるなら教えいただけると助かります。
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 残念ですが、インタースティシャル広告は使用できません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ちなみにネイティブアド広告は表示することはできますか？

Comment: 試していないのでわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ons-modal`とnendの300x250サイズの広告を利用すれば、インターステーシャル広告もどきはできそうです。
JavaScriptで実現できます。
mBaaSの環境がないので、mBaaSでの組み合わせについては回答できません。

[image: インターステーシャル広告もどきのイメージ]

Comment: 無理なお願いに回答して頂き感謝しております。
素晴らしいアイディアですね。この考え方で進めていきます。
ありがとうございました。